# How can I fit text in label in Kivy?

Tags: python, label, font-size, kivy, python-3.4

I have a label with text that needs its `font_size` to fit in some rectangle. I think I should get size in pixels like this (formulas):

> # Device independent pixels
>
> px = dp * density
>
> # Scale independent pixels
>
> px = sp * density * fontscale
>
> # Points
>
> px = pt * dpi / 72.

But problem is that I can't get [dpi, density, fontscale](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html#kivy.metrics.Metrics), etc., it says:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Also it seems there is no built-in function that can fit the text.

Comment: Show full error message. There is number of line with problem - mark this line in your code.

Comment: Error means that you use some float variable `somename` as function `somename()`

Comment: @furas My bad, I must use it without `()`, although docs says otherwise. But anyway, is it a good way to fit text?

Comment: Where do the docs say otherwise? This is probably a mistake or some bad writing. You normally want to use dp, sp etc as functions. Also, I don't really understand your general question, could you be more specific about exactly what you expect these lines to do, or alternatively include more code showing your full goal rather than this specific part.

Comment: @Necronomicron problem is that you use some float variable **with** `()`. Show full error message. There is number of line with problem - mark this line in your code.

Comment: @inclement [Here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html#kivy.metrics.Metrics) you can see `dpi()` with **()**. Lines are just formulas, it's **not** a code! And I've already told that was my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I've found the solution.

```
class BlockLabel(Label):
    scale_factor = .9
    factor = dimension = None

    def on_texture_size(self, *args):
        if not self.factor:
            self.factor = [self.font_size / self.texture_size[0], self.font_size / self.texture_size[1]]
        if not self.dimension:
            self.dimension = 1 if self.texture_size[0] * self.size[1] < self.texture_size[1] * self.size[0] else 0
        self.font_size = self.size[self.dimension] * self.scale_factor * self.factor[self.dimension]
```

I've tested it only on squares (I mean text inscribed in square) for now, but it should work on rectangles too. Also if there are **only** squares, `self.size` can be removed like this:

```
self.dimension = 1 if self.texture_size[0] < self.texture_size[1] else 0
```

And I've tested this code only for one-line text, I don't know if it works for multi-line text correctly, although it should.

Answer (score 1):

I built up on @Necronomicron answer so that this codes works on rectangles. The problem (at least for me) was that the font_size calculation wasn't taking into account the width of the label, so if it got too small the letters would not be inside it.

I changed it to:

```
def on_texture_size(self, *args):
    try:
        if not self.factor:
            self.factor = [self.font_size / self.texture_size[0], self.font_size / self.texture_size[1]]

        self.font_size0 = self.size[0] * self.scale_factor * self.factor[0]
        self.font_size1 = self.size[1] * self.scale_factor * self.factor[1]

        if self.font_size0 < self.font_size1:
            self.font_size = self.font_size0
        else:
            self.font_size = self.font_size1
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
```

In this way the chosen font size is always the smallest, making sure that the text fits both vertically and horizontally. I also did this after the label (or button in my case) creation:

```
button1.bind(size=lambda x, y: button1.on_texture_size())
```

So that the text font_size is updated every time the button size changes (when the screen size changes, for example)